# satisfies operator doesn't narrow the type of variable

Tags: typescript

I'm having problems with type narrowing using `satisfies` operator.

Basically, I want the type of `br` to specify that `name` property is of type `"br"`:

```js
type RichTextCustomElement = {
    name: string;
    Button: React.ComponentType<any>;
    Element: React.ComponentType<any>;
    plugins?: RichTextPlugin[] | undefined;
}

const br = {
  name: "br",
  Button: Button,
  Element: Element,
  plugins: [plugin],
} satisfies RichTextCustomElement;
```

For some reason, the type of `br` is as follows:

```js
const br: {
    name: string;
    Button: FC<{
        path: string;
    }>;
    Element: FC<{
        attributes: Record<string, any>[];
        children: ReactNode;
    }>;
    plugins: RichTextPlugin[];
}
```

TypeScript correctly narrowed the types for `Button`, `Element` and `plugins` (to some extent), but type of `name` remained as `string`, not `"br"`.

For a moment, I thought it had something to do with `tsx`, but my hypothesis was quickly disproved. I created a `.ts` file in root of the project folder:

```js
type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};
const defaultUser = {
  id: "123",
  name: "Matt",
} satisfies User;
```

Type of `defaultUser`:

```js
const defaultUser: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

Wherein, `satisfies` operator in another parts of my project works as expected:

```js
type CollectionConfig = {
    slug: string;
    // ...
}
const MenuItems = {
  slug: COLLECTION.MENU_ITEMS,
  // ...
} satisfies CollectionConfig;
```

```js
const MenuItems: {
    slug: "menuItems";
    // ...
}
```

I don't have any idea as to why this is happenning. Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Can you try to change `satisfies RichTextCustomElement` to `satisfies RichTextCustomElement as const`?

Comment: `const br = {name: "br" as const, ...}` works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `satisfies` operator doesn't in every case. If the property has the predefined values like *string literals* it will work in that case, however if you have typed something as `string` it won't:

```
type Test = {
    narrowingWorks: 'a' | 'b';
    narrowingDoesntWork: string
}

// const testObj: {
//     narrowingDoesntWork: string;
//     narrowingWorks: "a";
// }
const testObj = {
    narrowingDoesntWork: "property isn't narrowed",
    narrowingWorks: 'a'
} satisfies Test
```

What you are actually looking for is [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), which prevents the compiler from widening types to their primitives. To make sure that values are type-safe you can combine the `satisfies` operator with the *const assertion*:

```
// const br: {
//     readonly name: "br";
// }
const br = {
  name: "br",
} as const satisfies Record<string, string>
```

Comment: I have to use the type described in the body of question. With `as const satisfies RichTextCustomElement`, typescript complains about immutability of property `plugins`: `Types of property 'plugins' are incompatible. The type 'readonly [RichTextPlugin]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'RichTextPlugin[]'.`

Comment: @Shmookoff turn `RichTextCustomElement.plugins` into `readonly RichTextPlugin[] | undefined`.

Comment: This error happens because read-only arrays are not assignable to mutable arrays

Comment: This type comes from a library, so I can't change it. I included it for reference.

Comment: @Shmookoff wrap it with `Readonly<>`

Comment: @Shmookoff You need to wrap the plugins instead of the full object. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASglgYwBYBUIA9gAUA2BXAczgDsoBeAbwEMAuAZ2ACcSCBfAKE9ElkVQ2ABhPAwD2AWwCiOCOIjFg5KBXZQ1UYlTk0oDZsQIBuVerD4ixOgH4d8ZGky5CJANoBdKAB8oeYgBMIADMSCD9jDnYEUUtFACNGJRU1TW0oACJ4tIAaEzNnSx0XahoAcioS1jcc1igqOigomN0qYDg6YIh6gHlxOGAAHjt+TGExKRk5BSyoEryLOhKAPigAMmU5kjpbCCo-aJwQQb4HIRFgCWlZeWAXWfNNkrdF1mMgA

Comment: @Shmookoff or use [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYCUIEMAmyB2ANiADwAqAfFALxQDeAUFFAE7Z5EhQDaA0lAEt8UANYQQyAGZQyAXQBcMvrKgQAHsAj4cCKHHwj8yAO75uKgPyt2BYjwB0jsspWL8EAG4QWAbgYBfPwYGUEgoAGU0CDJwaFpGZmYsNzhUACNvcz9-YNDoTFxbEBiw2ngkNAKOYhJI1GjYiiA) custom readonly over the whole object

Comment: @kennarddh thank you very much guys! This worked, I am still confused as to why is this the thing...

Comment: and what about the example with `User` type..?\

Comment: @Shmookoff check [this one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/PTAEDMEMBsGcFMBQAXAngB3qAwpBBGUAXlACd5IATAewDtpVRaBXAWwCN5SBtAXVHgAPZPFqVYTNpx78A-KGSlmWAFwQYCANyIQCpUjSYceeACZikjlz4Dho8WQo16jFlZmh5i5aDVQ48NpAA) as explanation why

Comment: just do `const assertion` on user as well

Comment: It's just that I took the user example from an [article](https://www.totaltypescript.com/clarifying-the-satisfies-operator), so I imagine it has to work..?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm still a bit confused as to why in some parts of my project `satisfies` works as expected (`menuItems` example), and in other it does not (`defaultUser` and `br` examples).

Comment: @Shmookoff Because in the `menuItems` you use a constant value from another object.  `br` is marked as a string in the type and it does satisfy the type `string`, which is why you don't get it narrowed. If you would change its type to a literal union(`"a" | "b"`) it would narrow it

Comment: Oh.. That totally makes sense! `COLLECTION` is indeed an object that is marked with `as const`. Could you please update the answer so that it includes this bit of info?

Comment: And I think I misread the article I linked with the defaultUser example. It does not talk about type narrowing there, or does it?

Comment: @Shmookoff I don't see any article. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer! The article I was talking about: https://www.totaltypescript.com/clarifying-the-satisfies-operator